# R: cannot grep() on "+" character?

Tags: regex, r, grepl

Here is my data:

```
> rep$strand
  [1] - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
  [58] - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - + + +
  [115] + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + +
  [172] + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + +
  [229] + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + +
```

In hopes of separating the `"+"` from the `"-"`, I tried running the following commands.

```
grepl("-",rep$strand) #this gives me a list of TRUE/FALSE that seems correct
grepl("+",rep$strand) #this is all TRUE for some mysterious reason
```

I can't figure out why the same `grepl()` command would work on `"-"` but not on `"+"`.

Comment: `+` is a regex metachar. you'd need to escape it to remove its "metaness".

Comment: ...which is done with backslashes. Two of them.

Comment: or grepl("+", "some + in here", fixed=TRUE)

Comment: you can find more details about regex in the documentation: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
grepl("\\+", rep$strand)
```

or

```
grepl("+", rep$strand, fixed = TRUE)
```

or

```
"+" == rep$strand
```

Comment: +1 for completeness, but for the first, would it be more correct to use `^\\+$` to be equivalent with the other two?

Comment: @BrodieG The first two commands are equivalent. I agree, that one can use `^\\+$` in the first command to make it equivalent to the third one. However, the second command cannot be equivalent to the third one.